# Programmatically resize NSView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, resize, nsview, cgrect

I have a main view that is supposed to display several subviews. Those subviews are directly above and below one another (in the z axis) and will drop down (in the y axis) and move up using this code:

```
if (!CGRectIsNull(rectIntersection)) {
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectOffset (rectIntersection, 0, -2);
    [backgroundView setFrame:newFrame];
} else{
    [viewsUpdater invalidate];
    viewsUpdater = nil;
}
```

rectIntersection is used to tell when the view has entirely moved down and is no longer behind the front one (when they no longer overlap rectIntersection is null), it moves down by 2 pixels at a time because this is all inside a repeating timer. I want my main view, the one that contains these two other views, to resize downward so that it expands just as the view in the background is being lowered. This is the code I'm trying for that:

```
CGRect mainViewFrame = [mainView frame];
if (!CGRectContainsRect(mainViewFrame, backgroundFrame)) {
    CGRect newMainViewFrame = CGRectMake(0,
                                         0,
                                         mainViewFrame.size.width,
                                         (mainViewFrame.size.height + 2));
    [mainView setFrame:newMainViewFrame];
}
```

The idea is to check if the mainView contains this background view. When the backgroundView is lowered, the main view no longer contains it, and it (should) expand downward by 2 pixels. This would happen until the background view stopped moving and the mainView finally contains backgroundView.

The problem is that the mainView is not resizing at all. the background view is being lowered, and I can see it until it disappears off the bottom of the mainView. mainView should have resized but it does not change in any direction. I tried using setFrame and setBounds (with and without setNeedsDisplay) but nothing worked.

I'm really just looking for a way to programmatically change the size of the main view.

Comment: why not resizing the `mainView`, just before or after moving the `backgroundView` downward ? Is the `mainView`'s frame size the same as the `backgroundView`'s one ? try logging frames size.

Comment: I have no idea how to resize the view at all. I tried making a new rect exactly the same, except with a slightly bigger height. The setting my view frame/bounds to that new rect, but it didn't change size. And I don't know how to log frame size.

Comment: Try `NSLog(@"view frame : %.2f, %.2f", view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);`

Comment: That worked. I can see the frame is changing. I've edited a few things and now I think the problem is that the frame has been expanding upward. Since the frame is near the top, but the origin by default is the bottom left, I think it's resizing upward, and nothing appears to change. How can i get it to resize downward?

Comment: to resize "downward", move the origin as you resize. try moving the origin by 2 along the y axis, `CGRectMake(0, mainFrameView.origin.y-2,
mainViewFrame.size.width, (mainViewFrame.size.height + 2));`.

Comment: I tried this but didn't notice any change. I logged the origin coordinates and they did not change. What's weird is that even though the height and the origin are changed in the same way, the height changes but the origin doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understood, what the problem is. I read carefuly the code.

```
if (!CGRectIsNull(rectIntersection)) {
    // here you set the wrong frame
    //CGRect newFrame = CGRectOffset (rectIntersection, 0, -2);
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectOffset (backgroundView.frame, 0, -2);
    [backgroundView setFrame:newFrame];
} else{
    [viewsUpdater invalidate];
    viewsUpdater = nil;
}
```

`rectIntersection` is actually the intersection of the two views, that overlap, and as the `backgroundView` is moved downward, that rect's height decreases.
That way the `mainView` gets resized only one time.

To add on this, here is a simple solution using block syntax, to animate your views, this code would typically take place in your custom view controller.

```
// eventually a control action method, pass nil for direct call
-(void)performBackgroundViewAnimation:(id)sender {
    // first, double the mainView's frame height
    CGFrame newFrame = CGRectMake(mainView.frame.origin.x,
                                  mainView.frame.origin.y,
                                  mainView.frame.size.width,
                                  mainView.frame.size.height*2);
    // then get the backgroundView's destination rect
    CGFrame newBVFrame = CGRectOffset(backgroundView.frame,
                                      0,
                                      -(backgroundView.frame.size.height));
    // run the animation
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{
                                     mainView.frame = newFrame;
                                     backgroundView.frame = newBVFrame;
                                 }
    ];
}
```